# Using WP_Query() in Magento shows error

Tags: wp-query, magento

I am using Magento (directory `example.com/app`) and WordPress  (directory `example.com/blog/wp-blog-header.php`).

When I set up a `WP_Query` in Magento's `template\catalog\product\view.phtml` it shows the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare __() (previously declared in \app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php:93) in wordpress\wp-includes\l10n.php on line 98

Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Milo,do you know how to correct it?

Comment: Seems like magento is declaring functions using same names as WordPress. `__` is a localization function in WP. interested if someone got a solution.

Comment: This is in [`app/functions.php`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/f98550dd6d7f32951c0221cbb0a0e68086d780c7/app/functions.php) now.

Answer (score 2):

`__()` is deprecated in magento. You may either manually delete it from the magento core files (& repeat this process again everytime you have a new install or you upgrade) or wait for magento developers to remove this.

For wordpress, in the future when php 5.3 is much more common & wordpress breaks their backward compatibility & push all their code to namespaces then only this will be solved. I think this won't be anytime soon(maybe never?).

**BOTTOM LINE:** Since wordpress relies on this function for some functionality & it's deprecated in magento, go for deleting it from core files in magento. You already have the path & line number (\app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php:93)

If this doesn't work for you, you can't do what you asked for in the question. My suggestion for an alternative is to create a wordpress script which could dump the required information to some database then create a magento script to read it from there & run them individually (maybe setup a cron)